# How is an EEA national processed if he/she applies for entry to the UK under the UK immigration rules rather than EEA regulations?

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens

[The home Office Website](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/eea-nationals-eun01/eea-nationals-eun01#eun13-what-rights-do-eea-nationals-have-to-live-and-work-in-the-uk) states:

> EUN1.10 Can EEA nationals apply under the Immigration Rules?
>
> Yes. If an EEA national wishes to apply under the immigration rules, they are entitled to do so.

My question is: if I do this, as opposed to applying under EEA regulations, how would it affect the way I'm processed?

Comment: Why would anyone ever need to do so?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [fourth bullet point](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Generally no difference, some people find the UK strategy offers advantages that the EEA route does not offer. But it's an Expats thing not a Travel thing.  Off topic here, sorry